# Inequality Proof by Contradiction

Tags: proof-writing

I need help setting up the following proof:

Prove that $0 ≤ a < b$ implies $0 ≤ a^2 < b^2$ and $0 ≤ a^{(1/2)} < b^{(1/2)}$.

I am thinking proof by contradiction is the right method, I just dont know how to start it.

Comment: Not necessarily; consider the non trivial part: $a < b$. But $a \ge 0$ and thus we can multiply both terms of the inequality without changing its "direction", i.e. $aa < ab$. And the same with $b \ge 0$ : $ab < bb$. Thus, "joining them": $0 \le aa < ab < bb$.

Answer (score 0):

assuming $$a^2\geq b^2$$ this is equivalent to
$$a^2-b^2\geq 0$$ or $$(a-b)(a+b)\geq 0$$ this means $$a\geq b$$ which is a contradiction to $a<b$.
in the case of $$a^{1/2}\geq b^{1/2}$$ we get by squaring (all positive) $$a\geq b$$ which contrdicts $$0\le a<b$$

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply inequalities memberwise when the terms are non-negative and you can write

$$0\le a<b\implies 0\le a^2<b^2$$ directly.

Then by definition

$$0\le\sqrt a$$

and $$\sqrt a\ge\sqrt b\implies a\ge b,$$ which would be contradictory with $a<b$.